# Microsoft Graph REST API download does not respond

Tags: c#, rest, graph

I am calling the Microsoft Graph REST API and everything works like getting folder listings, deleting files and uploading files etc.  I cannot get downloads to work though.  I get the @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl but when I try the Url it never repsonds and just times out.

Any ideas?